# Configuration issue with nginx, passenger & Ruby on Rails "no such file to load -- config/environment"

Tags: linux, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I recently got a Linode and followed a guide on how to set up [Ruby On Rails with Nginx on Debian 5](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/debian-5-lenny).

Everything seems to be setup properly (no errors or issues following that guide). I've uploaded the Ruby application I was working on locally, updated the nginx.conf file to point to the application and am now getting an error:

```
no such file to load -- config/environment
```

Please see [this screen capture of the error](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0aa3pht98) for full details. I have tried changing permissions on the environment.rb file. I think I'm missing something very basic. For what it's worth, the site does work locally in a Mac environment.

[Here is a snippet of my nginx log.](http://pastebin.com/qk09cLyJ)

Here's the site in my nginx conf file:

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     *.mydomain.com;

  root            html/simple_cms/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_use_global_queue on;
}
```

I'm a complete newbie both in the Linux environment and as a Ruby developer. So any advice would be well taken and much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This should be an absolute path:

```
root /some/path/html/simple_cms/public;
```